# How to use the new form_kwargs on an inline formset?

Tags: django, django-forms

In 1.9, there's a new `form_kwargs` [feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) for `formset_factory` which allows you to set a queryset for a specific field in the `formset`. My question is, how do I achieve the same thing for an `inlineformset_factory`?

Doing the following doesn't work:

```
/* Pseudo code of my actual models */
class Account(models.Model):
    fields here...

class Invoice(models.Model):
    fields here...

class InvoiceLineItem(models.Model):
    account = ForeignKey(Account)
    invoice = ForeignKey(Invoice)
    description = CharField
    amt = DecimalField

/* === End of Pseudo Code === */


# Real code that fails:

InvoiceLineItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceLineItem, fields=('description', 'account', 'amt'))
accts = Account.objects.filter(fund__pk = self.kwargs['fpk'])
invoice_line_item_form = InvoiceLineItemFormset(form_kwargs={'account':accts})
```

Error that I get is:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'account'
```

And the error is highlighting the following two lines from the template:

```
{{ invoice_line_item_form.management_form }}
{% for ili in invoice_line_item_form %}
```

I'm not sure if I'm implementing this wrong (since it's designed for `formset_factory` and I'm using it on `inlineformset_factory`) or if I've set it up wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class InvoiceLineItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.account = kwargs.pop('account')
        super(InvoiceLineItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['account'].queryset = self.account

InvoiceLineItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Invoice, InvoiceLineItem, form=InvoiceLineItemForm,
    fields=('description', 'account', 'amt'))

formset = InvoiceLineItemFormSet(form_kwargs={'account': account})
```

Comment: Your solution was very close. I had to add the following just after the call to `super` in the `ModelForm`: `self.fields['account'].queryset = self.account`. If you update your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Garfonzo Edited. Thanks!

Comment: I searched for a "form_kwargs" like feature for so many times to get custom parameters from formset forms in a clean way.. I didn't found it in documentation but in a django ticket (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18166). Thanks for the example ;-)