# Getting a WARNING and ERROR: unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Tags: arguments, warnings, django-queryset, django-errors

Unexpected keyword argument 'queryset' in constructor call [E:unexpected-keyword-arg]

Tried using form_kwargs as shown on stack overflow here:
        # [How to use the new form_kwargs on an inline formset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560344/how-to-use-the-new-form-kwargs-on-an-inline-formset)

```
if request.method == "POST":
    ctx['formset'] = project_comparison_form_set(
        data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, queryset=ctx['projects'])  
    ctx['data1'] = request.POST.copy

    if ctx['formset'].is_valid():
        instances = ctx['formset'].save(commit=False)
        for project in instances:
            project.save()
```

Getting both a warning and error message in pylint Unexpected keyword argument 'queryset' in constructor call [E:unexpected-keyword-arg]

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `project_comparison_form_set` is defined, but i assume that it is a `modelformset_factory`.

Here, you do not have the queryset argument. If you do want to pass a queryset, you can pass it to the formset and the formset than to the modelformset_factory.

Check the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset.